# Can one ensure user-provided code does not have access to a variable that needs to be available in the same scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security

In my current task I have to run user code. Their code needs to use a token that I'm providing them to access some resources. However, I only want this token to be used for the resource access. I do not want the user code to have any possibility in reading (and subsequently storing) the token. This resource access can occur at any point in the user code and an unlimited amount of times. The resource access will load some variables that the user has defined earlier.

I've tried securing the token's visibility by putting it in a function that can only be accessed by passing in a uuid I'm generating at run time. Unfortunately, I keep running into the same sort of problem where a user could feasibly obtain the token through a mixture of printing the function bodies and making the function calls used to access the token. The problem appears to be due to the token access process' context being intermingled with the user code's context. This gives the user code the ability to make any function call that is used to try and hide the token.

This is an example of what the user code could look like. Explanations of the resource access pattern are inline.

```
const userVar = resource.getVar(); // This variable isn't loaded initially.
console.log(userVar); // unloaded placeholder

await resource.retrieve(); // This is the resource access request. It will make a roundtrip and load all previous requests to resource.

console.log(userVar); // Some value
```

This is how I tried to secure the resource access and failed due to context intermingling. Essentially inserting code into the user code to ensure the token is only known about when the resource needs to be accessed.

```
resource.removeToken(); // Now resource has no knowledge of the token.

const userVar = resource.getVar();
console.log(userVar); // unloaded placeholder

resource.setToken(getToken("RANDOMLY GENERATED RUNTIME CODE")); // resource knows what the token is now.
await resource.retrieve();
resource.removeToken(); // Now resource has no knowledge of the token.

console.log(userVar); // Some value
```

The problem with this solution is that if the user has a function that calls resource.retrieve(), then my solution will wrap that line with the function used to acquire the token. Thus, the user can call their function's toString() method and find out what the access code used to get the token is. This leaves the possibility that the user code can maliciously figure out what the token is.

Comment: Whats your usecase? You seem to have an XY problem

Comment: Use `Object.defineProperty` to create a getter function that returns the token only when feasible

Comment: "*`const userVar = resource.getVar();
userVar === undefined; /* magic ? */ userVar === Some value`*" is not possible. If `getVar` did return the value `undefined`, that value cannot change into something else.

Comment: "*I keep running into the same sort of problem where a user could feasibly obtain the token through a mixture of printing the function bodies and making the function calls used to access the token.*" - just provide the user a closure function that closes over a variable containing the token, instead of containing the token (in string form) itself. Assuming the code where the closure is built is not accessible to the user, this is safe.

Comment: What's wrong with the user gaining access to the token? What else can they do with it apart from retrieving resources at arbitrary times (as they can with the function you intend to give them)? Simply fix that root problem, and give them an appropriate token that only authorises them to do what you want to allow them to do.

Comment: @Psi That's the problem, I'm unsure how to write a getter that the user code can't call while other objects can call in the same context.

Comment: @Bergi I edited the "undefined" to be a placeholder val instead, fair point.The token can be used in apis and services that are different from the apis accessible in the user code's execution context. Moreover, user code can be shared, so a user could execute someone else's script with their credentials. Thus if the user gained access to the token, they would be able to access the other apis and services on behalf of a different user. So the user should not be able to access the token in any form.

Comment: Well... It can be _called_, but it doesn't return a value in these cases. However, what prevents the consumer to just store the result?